# Xcodeのクロージャをチェーンさせるときのインデント設定

Tags: swift, xcode

https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit
のREADME.md
には

```
firstly {
    when(fulfilled: fetchImage, fetchLocation)
}.done { image, location in
    self.imageView.image = image
    self.label.text = "\(location)"
}.ensure {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
}.catch { error in
    self.show(UIAlertController(for: error), sender: self)
}
```

のようにインデントされていて、とても読みやすいと思います。

しかし、自分の`Xcode10.0`では下記のようにインデントされてしまいます。
（`Xcode9`でもこうだった記憶があります）

```
firstly {
    when(fulfilled: fetchImage, fetchLocation)
    }.done { image, location in
        self.imageView.image = image
        self.label.text = "\(location)"
    }.ensure {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
    }.catch { error in
        self.show(UIAlertController(for: error), sender: self)
}
```

READMEのように自動でインデントさせる設定方法はありますか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

なさそうです。

https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2188
に報告されていました。

> Type: Bug
>   Status:OPEN  (View Workflow)
>   Priority: Medium

という状況です。